# Is there anyway to prevent creating mutiple files from script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm now working on a project to create pdf files automatically from google sheet by using a script.

However, I faced a problem that eveytime I want to create pdf files, the files that already created previously also being re-created. So, I want to know if there's solution to this problem.

```
function createBulkPDFs() {
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxx");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxx");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxx");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("xxxxxxxx");
  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 2,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();

data.forEach(row => {
  createReport(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5], docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder, row[4] + " " + row[0]);
});
}

function createReport(date,location,weather,department,projectname,contractor,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder,pdfName) {
 
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId()); 
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{date}",date); //row 0
  body.replaceText("{location}",location); //row 1
  body.replaceText("{weather}",weather); //row 2
  body.replaceText("{department}",department); //row 3
  body.replaceText("{projectname}",projectname); //row 4
  body.replaceText("{contractor}",contractor); //row 5
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  
}
```

All credits goes to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9uU_KwGgzQ&t=27s
thank you in advance for answers

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a new column to keep track of the rows for which files were already created. In this case, you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `data` array to keep only unprocessed rows. You'd also need to update the spreadsheet to mark the row as processed after creating the file.

If there won't be two files with the same name, perhaps a simpler option would be to [look for the file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbynamename) in the folder before creating it. Extending the snippet you posted:

```
function createReport(date,location,weather,department,projectname,contractor,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder,pdfName) {
  // Return if a file with that name already exists
  if (pdfFolder.getFilesByName(pdfName).hasNext()) {
    return;
  }


  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId()); 
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{date}",date); //row 0
  body.replaceText("{location}",location); //row 1
  body.replaceText("{weather}",weather); //row 2
  body.replaceText("{department}",department); //row 3
  body.replaceText("{projectname}",projectname); //row 4
  body.replaceText("{contractor}",contractor); //row 5
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  
}
```